# loop through JSON array from List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, ajax, json

I am sending C# `List<string>` to AJAX JSON method. But How can I iterate that JSON array?

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetPreviousSaltsAndHashes(string name)
    {
        List<string> prevSalts = new List<string>();
       ....
       ....              
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {                      
                    prevSalts.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }

            }

            conn.Close();            


        return prevSalts;
    }


 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'NewPassword.aspx/GetPreviousSaltsAndHashes',
            data: "{'name':'" + username + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                PreviousSalts = data.d;
                alert(PreviousSalts);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var exception = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);                  
                alert(exception.Message);
            }
        });

//below part is not working. What is the way to iterate?
 $.each(PreviousSalts, function (index, PreviousSalt) {
                console.log(PreviousSalt);
                pass = $('#txtNewPass1').val();
                var combo = pass + PreviousSalt;
                var hash = new String(CryptoJS.SHA3(combo, { outputLength: 512 }));

                if (hash == newhash) {
                    alert("matched");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Describe "not working". Are you getting an error message? What does `console.log(PreviousSalt);` say, and what are you expected it to say? What does the received JSON look like? You need to be more specific in your question so we can help you!

Comment: You must do all of your work in the ajax callback. When execution reaches the `$.each` call, `PreviousSalts` has not yet been populated by the result of the AJAX request. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to Web API if possible. ASMX is being phased out and has poor JSON support. I've been able to force ASMX to return JSON like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GetPreviousSaltsAndHashes(string name)
{
    List<string> prevSalts= //blah blah, retrieve data
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType="application/json";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prevSalts));
}
```

Obviously, you lose content negotiation and you're using outdated technology. You should switch to [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). In fact, the code would largely be the same as what you posted. You just need to fix the routes.

Your JavaScript never reaches the `$.each` line with any data. That's because jQuery AJAX is asynchronous by default. It'll call the success function after it's received the response. So place that code in a function and tell jQuery's success handler what function to call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'NewPassword.aspx/GetPreviousSaltsAndHashes',
        data: "{'name':'" + username + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            PreviousSalts = data.d;               
            alert(PreviousSalts);
            HandleResponse(PreviousSalts);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var exception = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);                  
            alert(exception.Message);
        }
    });

 function HandleResponse(PreviousSalts){
 $.each(PreviousSalts, function (index, PreviousSalt) {
            console.log(PreviousSalt);
            pass = $('#txtNewPass1').val();
            var combo = pass + PreviousSalt;
            var hash = new String(CryptoJS.SHA3(combo, { outputLength: 512 }));

            if (hash == newhash) {
                alert("matched");
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to serialize your list into JSON.  JSON is simply a JavaScript string representation of your data.  .NET provides easy functions to make this happen.  Here's a post with great info:

[Serializing a list to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json)

Second, unless the .each code snippet is properly embedded into a callback already, you need to call that code from the success method of your AJAX request.