# Can't find a certain item in DB if it's name is duplicated

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm going to speak about ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application.

I have a database of users (Entity Framework). I can add, delete or search for user by his name or email, or both. It works fine if, for example, I search for "George" and there is only one George in the table. But if there are more users with these name, I need to show them all. Insted I have an exception.

Here is my controller's action for Search:

```
[HttpPost]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public ActionResult Search(User userinfo) 
{
    const string noResult = "Search Result Not Found";
    var itemforSearch = new User();
    using (var uc = new UserContext()) 
    {
        if (userinfo.Name == null && userinfo.Email == null)
        {
            List<User> users;
            users = uc.UserList.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = null };
        }
        if (userinfo.Name != null) 
        {
            itemforSearch = uc.UserList.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name == userinfo.Name);
            return GetSearchedItem(noResult, itemforSearch);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (userinfo.Email != null) 
            {
                itemforSearch = uc.UserList.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Email == userinfo.Email);
                return GetSearchedItem(noResult, itemforSearch);
            }
        }
    }
    return View(itemforSearch);
}

private ActionResult GetSearchedItem(string noResult, Models.User itemforSearch) 
{
    if (itemforSearch != null) 
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = itemforSearch };
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new Exception("User with provided information was not find");
    }
}
```

Here is my script that works after clicking "Search" button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DbSearch() {
    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var serchedName = $("input[name='SearchName']").val(),
        searchedEmail = $("input[name='SearchEmail']").val();

    var user = { Name: serchedName, Email: searchedEmail };

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "Search",
        data: JSON.stringify({ userinfo: user }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: OnSearchSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });
}

function OnSearchSuccess(data) {

    var tableContent = "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + data.UserId + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + data.Name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + data.Email + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $('#UserTable').empty();
    $("#UserTable").append(tableContent);
    $("#UserTable").fnDraw();
}
function OnError(data) { }
</script>
```

Actually, I think the problem is in my LINQ expression, when I use `SingleOrDefault` (I got {System.InvalidOperationException} but how can i fix it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `SingleOrDefault` you will get an exception when the dataset has multiple rows that match your condition, This property is also explained in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451.aspx

If you want to return a **list of users** that match your request you should use the `.where()` method.

Like so: `itemforSearch = uc.UserList.Where(o => o.Name == userinfo.Name).ToList();`

Or if you just want a **single matching** row you can use `.firstOrDefault()`.

Like this: `itemforSearch = uc.UserList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == userinfo.Name);`

---

**EDIT further explanation on returning multiple user result**
The controller and the `GetSearchedItem` function would need to use `List<User>()` to return multiple users as result, and in the view, the `function OnSearchSuccess(data)` would need to loop through the list of users.

Below I have modified the controller to use List but I'm not sure how to use JsonResult with a list so you would have to look that up if it doesn't work.

```
[HttpPost]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public ActionResult Search(User userinfo) 
{
    const string noResult = "Search Result Not Found";
    var itemforSearch = new List<User>();
    using (var uc = new UserContext()) 
    {
        if (userinfo.Name == null && userinfo.Email == null)
        {
            List<User> users;
            users = uc.UserList.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = null };
        }
        if (userinfo.Name != null) 
        {
            itemforSearch = uc.UserList.Where(o => o.Name == userinfo.Name).ToList();
            return GetSearchedItem(noResult, itemforSearch);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (userinfo.Email != null) 
            {
                itemforSearch = uc.UserList.Where(o => o.Email == userinfo.Email).ToList();
                return GetSearchedItem(noResult, itemforSearch);
            }
        }
    }
    return View(itemforSearch);
}

private ActionResult GetSearchedItem(string noResult, List<Models.User> itemforSearch) 
{
    if (itemforSearch.Count > 0) 
    {
        // Not sure how JsonResult works with lists but try take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json
        return new JsonResult { Data = itemforSearch };
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new Exception("User with provided information was not find");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one, but I had the next error: `Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type 'MyTask.Models.User'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

Comment: That would be because `itemforSearch` is not a list, If you want to be able to return multiple rows found by the search you will need to change `itemforsearch` into a list `var itemforSearch = new List<User>();`, and than you also would have to change your view to handle a list instead of just a single object.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that my `itemForSearch` has to be a list, but was I need to change in my view?

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation to my answer, when you return the results as a list your javascript code in your view would also have to loop trough the list of found users.

Comment: I see, now it's clear for me, thanks a lot for the quick answer and explanation!)