# how to convert an array of objects to json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an array of objects. now I want to convert them to json.

```
var dd =new MyUser[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
            dd[i] = new MyUser();
            dd[i].Status = 1;
            dd[i].TokenReg = "wsdfaf";
        }
```

how can I convert `dd` array to json ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to use JSON.NET:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dd);
```

You can install it via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
 PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Have a look at the [project page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

(You can also download it for free if you use Unity)

The output may look something like the following:

```
[
   {
       "Status":1,
       "TokenReg":"wsdfaf"
   },
   {
       "Status":1,
       "TokenReg":"wsdfaf"
   },
   {
       "Status":1,
       "TokenReg":"wsdfaf"
   },
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may do the trick

```
JObject json = new JObject();
var finalJson = json.Serialize(dd);
```