# Circular Reference for Entity in JSON Serialization error even with disabled lazy loading

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have been browsing through answers on stackoverflow for this problem and people wrote about disabling lazyloading and disabling proxycreation. But it did not help.
Here is my code.

```
        public ActionResult GetBooks()
    {
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var ksiazki = (from b in db.books join a in db.authors on b.fk_author_id equals a.author_id select new { b, a }).ToList();

            return Json(ksiazki, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
    }
```

When I try to enter url /x/GetBooks, I got the serialization error for the entity model of books

Comment: You can use a library like Newtonsoft Json or FastJson to do the json serialization for you...check the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json

Comment: Just return an anonymous object containing only those properties you need in the client.