# How to put json List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
        List<Object> lstsData = new List<object>();
        try
        {
            var thisWeekStart = Date.AddDays(-(int)Date.DayOfWeek);
            var thisWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
            var q = from c in db.Tasks select c.TaskName;
            var Taskss = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.TaskName != null).Select(x => x.TaskName);
            var HourSum = db.TimesheetData.Where(x => x.Date >= thisWeekStart && x.Date <= thisWeekEnd).GroupBy(x => x.TaskID).
            Select(grp => new { /*TaskID = grp.Key,*/ HourSum = grp.Sum(x => (double?)x.Hours ?? 0) });
            lstsData.Add(new { Hourss = HourSum, Taskname = q });
            return Json(lstsData);
        }
```

My issue is when i am trying return json then my data placed inside array. This is my console data

```
     {Hourss: Array(3), Taskname: Array(3)}
     length
     :
     1
   __proto__
    :
    Array(0)
```

My issue is when i am trying return json then my data placed inside array.

Comment: Why can't you simply return the list as it is, like this: return lstsData;

Comment: This question is of a low quality. Please give info on what are you trying to do. My quess is your query is not working correctly and this has nothing to do with json since that part is showing exactly what you are adding to the list.

Comment: @TonyMathew i can't use simple return lstsData because i want data in json response

Comment: Also is the DayName actually suppose to be TaskName since there is no DayName in the original query?

Comment: @FilipCordas i  want var Hours and q into my json response.

Comment: @FilipCordas thats my another json response .DayName is my another json response that i want same my var Hours and q into json response.

Comment: @Y.verma what's your return type? Is it JsonResult?

Comment: @TonyMathew  yes it is json type

Comment: Again from what I can see you want to return total hours for each task in the given period, right?

Comment: It will help a lot if you write the code without the vars but with the actual types. We and you will be able to understand better.

Comment: @FilipCordas yes you are right

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost certain you what is this query.

```
  var resultData = from task in db.Tasks
                                 where task.IsActive == true && task.TaskName != null
                                 join timesheet in db.TimesheetData on task.Id equals timesheet.TaskId
                                 where timesheet.Date >= thisWeekStart && timesheet.Date <= thisWeekEnd
                                 group new { task, timesheet } by new { task.Id, task.TaskName } into taskTime
                                 select new { TaskName = taskTime.Key.TaskName, Hours = taskTime.Sum(tt => tt.timesheet.Hours) };

return Json(resultData.ToArray());
```

What you want is to join the two tables based on the Id. The JSON serialization turns all ienumerable/iqueryable into JSON arrays. You just didn't write a proper query to return the data.

Comment: @Flip Cordas Thanks a lot my issue is solved  you write a  correct query.

Comment: @Y.verma You should try to rewrite the question because next time people might not be able to figure out what problem are you having and asking a good question is important if you want to use SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
lstsData.Add(new { Hourss = HourSum, Taskname = q });
```

`HourSum` and `q` are still `IQueryable` form. You should execute them to retrieve data from database.

Just try like this;

```
lstsData.Add(new { Hourss = HourSum.ToList(), Taskname = q.ToList() });
```

Comment: not working same value come that i given into my question.

Comment: What would you expect ? Of course the returned Hourss and Taskname data stored in an array. For example you could navidate it like response.Hourss[0] or iterate it like response.Hourss

Comment: He just ask a bad question he didn't know how to do a join for the two arrays.