# Represent a list of integers in json format

Tags: c#, json

I am creating a list like this

```
List<int> items = new List<int>();
```

items contains the following numbers

```
1006
1007
```

I want to be able to represent these numbers in json and 
pass it to my webapi from postman. How can I represent these
numbers in json.

Comment: There are some many duplicates of this, does this answer your question? [Serializing a list to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json) Actually, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items)` will be enough

Comment: I am not looking to do that in code if you read my question very well. I want to see what it will look like after json convert. Remember I am passing this in postman not in code.

Comment: Then your question is not about code and programming, it seems to be off-topic here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass array of numbers in postman as a json, pass it like

```
[
   100,
   200
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In postman your json would (minimally) look like:

```
[1006, 1007]
```

If it has a name and is part of an object with some other stuff:

```
{ "something":"else", "items":  [1006, 1007]}
```

Comment: It does not have a name. Just those numbers

Comment: That's why I put the first form